# iAd interstitial not consis

Tags: ios, swift, iad, interstitial

I found this code provided by Daniel Storm in a different thread. Sorry, I could not ask my question there because I don't have enough reputation yet to comment. The code should display an ad each time the button associated with displayAd is clicked. However in testing it both in Simulator and on an actual device, the ad only displays the first time the button is clicked. Help please...

```
var iAdInterstitial = ADInterstitialAd() // Our ad
var iAdInterstitialView = UIView() // View to present our ad in
var adLoaded = false // Bool to keep track if an ad is loaded or not

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupAd()
}

@IBAction func displayAd(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (adLoaded) {
        // We have an ad that is loaded so lets present it
        self.view.addSubview(iAdInterstitialView)
        iAdInterstitial.presentInView(iAdInterstitialView)
    }
    else {
        // No ad has been loaded
        print("Ad not loaded")
    }

}

func setupAd() {
    // Set presentation to manual so we can choose when to present the interstitial
    // Setting this will also fetch an interstitial ad for us
    self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy.Manual
    iAdInterstitial.delegate = self // Set the delegate

    // Make our view the same size as the view we will be presenting in
    iAdInterstitialView.frame = self.view.bounds
}

func requestNewAd() {
    // This will fetch an ad for us
    ResizingTestViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()
    print("Requesting new ad")
}

@IBAction func presentAdButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (adLoaded) {
        // We have an ad that is loaded so lets present it
        self.view.addSubview(iAdInterstitialView)
        iAdInterstitial.presentInView(iAdInterstitialView)
    }
    else {
        // No ad has been loaded
        print("Ad not loaded")
    }
}

func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    // Kinda works as expected
    // Sometimes is called prematurely
    // Sometimes takes minutes after ad is dismissed to be called
    print("interstitialAdDidUnload")

    // Get new ad
    adLoaded = false
    iAdInterstitialView.removeFromSuperview()
    requestNewAd()
}

func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    // Failed to load ad so lets try again
    print("didFailWithError: \(error)")
    requestNewAd()
}

func interstitialAdWillLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    // There is an ad and it has begun to download
    print("interstitialAdWillLoad")
}

func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    // We got an ad
    print("interstitialAdDidLoad")
    adLoaded = true
}

func interstitialAdActionShouldBegin(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    print("interstitialAdActionShouldBegin")
    return true;
}

func interstitialAdActionDidFinish(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    // Done with this ad. Lets get a new one
    print("interstitialAdActionDidFinish")
    iAdInterstitialView.removeFromSuperview()
    adLoaded = false
    requestNewAd()
}
```